# RecursiveLeafOnlyDirectoryScanner

Tags: spring-integration

I'm using a RecursiveLeafOnlyDirectoryScanner as a scanner in inbound-channel-adapter to launch a spring batch job, but getting heap space issue frequently. Below is my intgeration context:

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="poll_IAG_File" scanner="recursiveScanner" directory="/tmp/DIR1/" channel="files" filter="compositeFilter">
    <int:poller id="pollerFlatFile" fixed-delay="10000" />
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Heap size in IBM websphere is : 1024(min) -2048(max). Need to know appropriate configurations for inbound channnel adapter or suggestions to avoid the heap issue.

Below is the system logs of IBM websphere.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.lang.StringCoding.trim(StringCoding.java:455)
        at java.lang.StringCoding.encode(StringCoding.java:624)
        at java.lang.String.getBytes(String.java:694)
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.list(Native Method)
        at java.io.File.list(File.java:984)
        at java.io.File.listFiles(File.java:1062)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.RecursiveLeafOnlyDirectoryScanner.listEligibleFiles(RecursiveLeafOnlyDirectoryScanner.java:35)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.RecursiveLeafOnlyDirectoryScanner.listEligibleFiles(RecursiveLeafOnlyDirectoryScanner.java:39)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.RecursiveLeafOnlyDirectoryScanner.listEligibleFiles(RecursiveLeafOnlyDirectoryScanner.java:39)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.RecursiveLeafOnlyDirectoryScanner.listEligibleFiles(RecursiveLeafOnlyDirectoryScanner.java:39)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.DefaultDirectoryScanner.listFiles(DefaultDirectoryScanner.java:64)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource.scanInputDirectory(FileReadingMessageSource.java:276)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource.receive(FileReadingMessageSource.java:250)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:111)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:184)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:51)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:143)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:141)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:273)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:52)
        at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:49)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:49)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:268)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:53)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:450)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:314)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:109)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:217)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:790)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
 * DirectoryScanner that lists all files inside a directory and subdirectories,
 * without limit. This scanner should not be used with directories that contain
 * a vast number of files or on deep trees, as all the file names will be read
 * into memory and the scanning will be done recursively.
 *
 * @deprecated in favor of {@link FileReadingMessageSource#setUseWatchService(boolean)} (when using Java 7 or later)
 */
@Deprecated
public class RecursiveLeafOnlyDirectoryScanner extends DefaultDirectoryScanner {
```

But I don't think that it is an issue for you because even if `RecursiveLeafOnlyDirectoryScanner` loads all the files to the memory that doesn't mean that `File` object is so big.

I'm pretty sure that the problem is somewhere downstream, where you read a content of those files and don't free memory after usage. That might be an `<aggregator>` with the `SimpleMessageStore` (by default). That might be any custom `FileListFilter` which consults files content and store it in its local cache. And so on.

I suggests you to run some JVM tool to analyze the memory for objects which eat all your heap.